# Removing colons and whitespace in one regular expression

Tags: regex

I use the following to remove white space and `:.`. For example ' e-post: ' becomes 'e-post'.

```
replace(/\s/g,"").replace(/:/g,"");
```

But I know there is a better way to do it by using only one 'replace'. What can I try next?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simplest way - use alternation:

```
replace(/\s|:/g,"");
```

You can probably also use a character class:

```
replace(/[\s:]/g,"");
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?:

```
replace(/\s|:/g,"");
```

However, this will only work when you are replacing both regexes with the same string. If you need something different, use your original approach.